# Latex and SymPy error

Tags: errors, python

I try to make some calculations inside LaTeX. Therefore I want to use Sympy. So I put `\usepackage{sympytex}` to the header and compile wit `pdflatex`. After compiling there occurs a `.sympy` file. The documentary of SympyTex tells to run these file now with `python`. If i do I receive the following error with `python`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ErsterVersuch.sympy", line 4, in <module>
    import sympytex
  File "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/sympytexpackage/sympytex.py", line 48, in <module>
    from string import strip
ImportError: cannot import name 'strip'
```

Maybe some can explain me the problem.

Comment: As already pointed out in the given answer, you are using a deprecated/removed Python method. You may be able to use the existing code with Python 2, but as the official support for Python 2 will end at the end of 2019, you should consider switching to Python 3. Please provide a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

The `string.strip()` method appears to be provided with Python 2.7 (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html?highlight=strip#string.strip))

> 7.1.6. Deprecated string functions
>
> The following list of functions are also defined as methods of string
>   and Unicode objects; see section String Methods for more information
>   on those. You should consider these functions as deprecated, although
>   they will not be removed until Python 3. The functions defined in this
>   module are:

but (as to be expected from quote above) not with Python 3.5 or later (see [there](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#helper-functions)).

You need to make sure you are using Python 2.x, not Python 3.x. (that's my guess at least).